# How should pagination allowing links to arbitrary pages be handled in a RESTful API?

Tags: rest, api-design

How should a RESTful API handle pagination in the situation where a client may want the ability to jump to arbitrary pages? Let's assume we are using the `Link` header in the way the [GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/#pagination) does:

```
Link: <https://api.github.com/user/repos?page=3&per_page=100>; rel="next", <https://api.github.com/user/repos?page=50&per_page=100>; rel="last"
```

The API, like many others, returns links to the next page, previous page, first page and last page. This does not account for the relatively common use-case of providing on the client-side links to **a range of pages**, and not just the next/previous/first/last. If, for example, the request returns 100 pages worth of results, the client may want to allow the ability to jump to an arbitrary page. How should this be done while adhering closely to the concepts of REST?

Some possible options:

- Just let the client infer the other links. You have the first and last page, it may be a reasonable assumption to modify the link to obtain the other pages. This seems to go against HATEOAS (which is always the principle of REST that seems to cause problems).
- Return a link to every page. This seems unwieldy as the potential number of pages could be high.
- Return a link to a small range of pages (perhaps 2 either side of the current page). This seems like a relatively sensible approach but it limits the options clients have when it comes to displaying pagination information.

Comment: What's the problem with the examples you just provided?

Comment: @RobertHarvey - The problem with the GitHub and JSONAPI examples is that they only allow navigation to the first/last/next/previous pages. If you have 100 pages the client may want to be able to jump to some arbitrary page.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - I've edited the question so I hope it significantly clearer now.

Comment: Well, according to the example you posted above, you can jump to any page of n pages given x items per page: `?page=3&per_page=100`.  So I'd say you have the ability to jump to anywhere you want.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - That is the first option I suggested, which could be seen as violating the principle of HATEOAS. It is by far the easiest option though. Jarrod's answer appears to suggest option 3 - return links to a range of pages centred around the current page.

Comment: You didn't mention HATEOAS in your question.  Is that your specific concern?

Comment: @RobertHarvey - It's mentioned in my first suggestion. My specific concern is simply how to allow for pagination of the type I've described (e.g. allows for jumping to any page) within the principles of REST, of which HATEOAS is one.

Comment: No, HATEOAS is an *additional constraint,* on top of REST.  Check the Wikipedia entry.  All it really means is that *you don't provide links to non-existent resources or actions.*

Comment: @RobertHarvey - "[If a service violates any of the required constraints, it cannot be considered RESTful](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#Uniform_interface)". I can't see any mention of the HATEOAS constraint being optional.

Comment: Alright, fair enough.  What prevents you from not supplying links to nowhere?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23508/discussion-between-robert-harvey-and-james-allardice).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

##The problem is the URL is not RESTful in the GitHub example:

I would rather see actual `URL` that represent the resource exclusively. It is not that hard if you put a little thought into it.

###To be truly RESTful the URI should be a resource identifier and nothing else

Parameters make it `RPC` over `HTTP` which is the opposite of the `REST` paradigm.

```
http://example.com/{user_id}/posts/first
http://example.com/{user_id}/posts/09/previous
http://example.com/{user_id}/posts/10
http://example.com/{user_id}/posts/11
http://example.com/{user_id}/posts/12
http://example.com/{user_id}/posts/13
http://example.com/{user_id}/posts/14
http://example.com/{user_id}/posts/15/next
http://example.com/{user_id}/posts/last
```

*Using parameters as part of the identifier is a bad practice, regardless of who is doing it.*

```
http://example.com/{user_id}/posts/09/to/04/ <- previous
http://example.com/{user_id}/posts/14/to/19/ <- next
```

No parameters and more concise and self describing as well.

###If the list is totally client side then fragment identifiers would be the correct choice:

Since fragments are never set to the server on requests they are totally client side references. [Fragment Identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) is considered a sub-location of the resource, which semantically `previous` and `next` are sub-locations of `posts/`

The specific example of RFC 5147 is applicable here `http://example.com/document.txt#line=10,20`

[RFC7233](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7233) specifies the binary `RANGE` header. That is a very compelling argument for a custom `PAGINATION_RANGE` header using the [RFC5988](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5988#page-6) `Link Header` in the same spirit.

```
http://example.com/{user_id}/posts/first
http://example.com/{user_id}/posts/09/#previous=5
http://example.com/{user_id}/posts/10
http://example.com/{user_id}/posts/11
http://example.com/{user_id}/posts/12
http://example.com/{user_id}/posts/13
http://example.com/{user_id}/posts/14
http://example.com/{user_id}/posts/15/#next=5
http://example.com/{user_id}/posts/last
```

###Fragments do not reload the page but do create history:

So you get correct forward/back button behavior for free!

Comment: Thanks, so the third option of the ones I suggested? The parameters etc. are just from some popular existing examples and not really relevant to the question. It's just the bit you've called 'varying links' that I'm interested in.

Comment: the parameters **are relevant** as they are a poor design choice as they clutter up the API and basically represent `RPC` over `HTTP GET` instead of a `REST` experience.

Comment: I agree, it's relevant to API design in general but not really relevant to my particular question (not my downvote though). Do you know of any public APIs that use the "varying links" technique you've demonstrated?

Comment: @JarrodRoberson - I've edited my question so I think it's quite a bit clearer. I wasn't asking whether the `Link` header was the correct solution, or whether query parameters were a good idea.

Comment: @JamesAllardice: [What do you mean by "good?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/142354/102937)

Comment: @JarrodRoberson: How does this scheme work with systems that allow the user to specify the number of records per page?  Won't you get a different result on a given URL if the specified number of records per page changes?

Comment: @RobertHarvey - Here I just mean "good" as in "good practice", as the OP states them to be bad practice. If you're referring to the question itself, I'm looking for a technical reasons why one of the options I suggested (or another option entirely) is objectively better than the others.